# Multiple queries on same table in one statement

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table for categories that looks like:

```
id    name    parent
1     cat1    0
2     cat2    0
3     cat3    1
4     cat4    1
5     cat5    2
```

Let's take the category 4, I would like to get the parent category (1) and its name (cat1) in the same SQL query.

So far I'm doing this like:

```
SELECT parent AS p FROM categories WHERE id=4;
```

Then in another query

```
SELECT name FROM categories WHERE id=p;
```

But given the size of the tables, I'd like to speed it up by turning these 2 queries into 1.

Comment: You need to LEFT JOIN the same table.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT parent, name FROM categories WHERE id=(SELECT parent FROM categories WHERE id=4);
```

Comment: Hi, this only gives me the name and parent of the category 4 (1 and cat4), I need to get the parent ID (which is 1), and the parent's name (which is cat1).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name FROM categories p, categories s WHERE s.id=4 AND p.id=s.parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done through left join.

```
SELECT 
   b.name as PCatName, b.parent as ParentID
FROM categories a 
LEFT JOIN categories b ON b.parent=a.parent AND b.id <> a.id
WHERE a.id=4
```